# unresolved overloaded function type for Wire.onReceive

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c

I am attempting to make an I2C slave out of my Arduino and I can't get past the Wire.onReceive function. Here is my code. The documentation says to just add a function that has the style of void myHandler(int bytes) but I can't figure out why my readPI function does not meet these requirements.

```C++
    #include "piCom.h"
    #include "WireAddresses.h"
    #include <Wire.h>

    pi::pi(){
       Wire.begin(NB_INFO); // is 0x04
       Wire.onReceive( readPI );
       //Wire.onRequest(sendPI);
    }

    void pi::readPI(int byteCount){
       while( Wire.available() ){

             ref_IMU = Wire.read();

       }//end while

    }//end readPI

    void pi::sendPI(){

       Wire.write(1);
       //use to send pressure info to pi

    }//end sendPI


    //double pi::getref_IMU(){return ref_IMU;}
```

then here is the error

```C++
piCom.cpp: In constructor 'pi::pi()':
piCom.cpp:7: error: no matching function for call to'TwoWire::onReceive(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
 Wire.onReceive( readPI );
                        ^

no matching function for call to 'TwoWire::onReceive(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    void pi::sendPI(){
```

That is a class function (method) which has an implicit **this** pointer. You can't use it as a static ISR.

In general, classes cannot implement ISRs for this reason. There are a few workarounds, one being to make it a **static** class function. However then it will affect the entire class, not just one instance.

Comment: I ended up just putting the functions inside the .ino file. it's not as neat as I'd like but it works. Thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: You can make a static class function (one that does not belong to a particular instance) and keep the function inside your class then.